# Dropdown menu only shows 2 lines instead of 3

Tags: html, css

My navbar shows only 2 of the submenu titles. Why is that?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #36527c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 121px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: Open sans hebrew;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: none;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.nav a.active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}


/* Sub Menus */

.nav li li {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: .8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="tutorials"><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorial #1@@</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorial #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorial #3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="about"><a class="active" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="news"><a href="#">Newsletter</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">News #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News #2@@@</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News #3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .nav UL CSS has a height set to 121px and unfortunately that doesn't just affect the first UL, it affects them all. Giving it a class or id you can bind to your height fixes that problem.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #36527c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.mainul {
  height: 121px;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: Open sans hebrew;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: none;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.nav a.active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}


/* Sub Menus */

.nav li li {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: .8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="mainul">
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="tutorials"><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorial #1@@</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorial #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorial #3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="about"><a class="active" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="news"><a href="#">Newsletter</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">News #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News #2@@@</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News #3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: its still dosent work for me .
maybe its because other divs affect the nav ?
i didnt copied them to the qoute

Comment: @DanShimonMedina you deleted height: 121px; from .nav ul and only have it in .mainul?